# Want to upgrade the my java 8 to use TLSV2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, tls1.2, okhttp

I need to connect to a restful endpoint using okHttp3.
The endpoint that I was given no longer support TLSV1.2 so i need a way to upgrade my TLS version on my java 8 application/ embedded Tomcat to 2.0, I was told by the developers of the endpoint that the TLS version might be the reason I cannot connect.

I tried changing the TLS version using the sslContext and it gave me an error saying invalid algorighm

This is the error that I get when I try to connect to the endpoint

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
```

Comment: `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` usually means the certificate is signed by a root CA certificate that is not in your Java certificate store.

Comment: @JimGarrison so I should ask them to provide me with the certificate?

Comment: Yes, you'll need the CA certificate of the root CA that signed the certificate presented by the service you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @JimGarrison thank you I will request that and see if it works.

Comment: @JimGarrison I think im now a bit confused. we are using a seflsigned certificate on our java application with other endpoints it connects except this one end point. the other google says that our jdk is not recognising our certificate. so I dont know hoe to go past this point.